# Remove Duplicates, but Honor Case

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove duplicates in data like:

[image]

I use code like:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

which produces:

[image]

I would like to keep words that have the same sequence of letters, but different case.  How would I achieve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the below code. It is assumed that data is in the range of A1 to A7, for different range you can modify the code.

```
Dim oDic As Object, vData As Variant, r As Long

Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Range("A1:A7")
    vData = .Value
    .ClearContents
End With

With oDic
    .comparemode = 0
    For r = 1 To UBound(vData, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(vData(r, 1)) And Not .Exists(vData(r, 1)) Then
            .Add vData(r, 1), Nothing
        End If
    Next r
    Range("A1").Resize(.Count) = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that may work for you. (It obviously has some crude coding elements, but I think you get the picture and can fix anything as needed):

```
Sub RespectCase()

Dim rSearch As Range, cel As Range, rFound As Range
Set rSearch = Range("G1:G10")
Set rFound = Range("J1:J10")

For Each cel In rSearch

    Dim rMatch As Range
    Set rMatch = rFound.Find(cel, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

    If rMatch Is Nothing Then

        Range("J10").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cel

    End If

Next

End Sub
```